# DataTable Not Being Cleared

Tags: c#, datatable

I am using a class variable `DataTable dt` and am attempting to run two SQL Queries and write the results to Excel.  I have no errors, and everything works fine, except on the second iteration and write to Excel, the headers from the datatable are written.

What I am after is sheet1 gets all the info from sqlquery1, then sheet2 gets all the info from sqlquery2.  Now datawise, it works exactly as I need, BUT sheet2 gets the headers from sqlquery1 for some reason.

Where in my syntax, do I not properly clear the datatable so that the next iteration starts with a clean slate?

```
public static void DoThis()
{
 string sqlsyntax = null;
 if (userid == "Red")
 {
    sqlsyntax = SQLQuery1 (just not showing syntax)
    QuerySQLTable(sqlsyntax);
    WriteDataToExcel(dt);
 }
 if (userid == "Pink")
 {
    sqlsyntax = SQLQuery2 (just not showing syntax)
    QuerySQLTable(sqlsyntax);
    WriteDataToExcel(dt);
 }
}

public static void QuerySQLTable(string sqlsyntax)
{
 using (conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnection))
 {
    //Clearing datatable if not null
    dt.Clear();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlsyntax, conn);
    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();             
 }
}

private static void WriteDataToExcel(DataTable dt)
{
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;

 for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
 {
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
 }

 for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    for (j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dt.Rows[i][j];
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO my understanding the `DataTable.Clear();` method simply clears the data from the `DataTable` while the `DataTable.Columns.Clear();` method will clear out the columns.

If I am understanding your problem correctly you are using the same `DataTable` for two writes to Excel, and write 1 has the headers
Field1, Field2, Field3 and write two has the headers Red1, Green1, Blue1 **BUT** on your worksheet for write2 you get the headers
Field1, Field2, Field3, Red1, Green1, Blue1

This is where the `DataTable.Columns.Clear()` method will come into play as it will clear the columns before the second write and ensure that with write one you **ONLY** get the headers
Field1, Field2, Field3
and for write two you **ONLY** get the headers
Red1, Green1, Blue1

Essentially try adding in `DataTable.Columns.Clear();` directly above the `DataTable.Clear()` call that you have and you should get the output in Excel just like you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dt.Clear();`

```
dt = new DataTable();
```

should work as you want. [@user2676140](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41211000/3729695) explained the reason.